# On hover of a checkbox, animate a different div

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, hover, jquery-animate

I would like the checkbox #video-checkbox, when hovered over, to animate the image #video as seen below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#video-checkbox").hover(function () {
        $("#video").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.75,
            marginTop: -10
        }, 400);
    }, function () {
        $("#video").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1.0,
            marginTop: 0
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/UBC8G/

Comment: Jeff, Still nothing happens.  Please see code at http://ifr.ifrhosting.net.

Comment: Works for me too, http://jsfiddle.net/8nvrG/

Comment: @mrpritchett: You are not including `jquery.js`.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provide it seems jQuery is not included in your page, $ is not defined. Download [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and link to it in your page's head tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **jQuery** source to your page.

You can download it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

[Minified version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js)

[Full version Development](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js)

Comment: DOH!  Had it loaded and must have taken it out by mistake...<facepalm>

Answer (score 0):

1: jQuery is not included on your page

2: There appears to be no tag with an ID of video on your page.